# How to delete a row of code in Java?

Tags: java

This is my code that I am working with right now and even if it sounds like the most easy problem ever I still want to know how to solve it. My problem is that i want the command `g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);` to be deleted when my player class goes under 100 hp.  I do not know how to do that.

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class HUD {


public static int HEALTH = 100;
public static int FULLHEALTH = 100;
private int greenValue = 255;

public void tick() {

    HEALTH = Game.clamp(HEALTH, 0, 100);
    greenValue = Game.clamp(greenValue, 0, 255);

    greenValue = HEALTH*2;


    if (HEALTH == 0)
        System.exit(1);

}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(15, 15, 200, 32);
    g.setColor(new Color(75, greenValue, 0));
    g.fillRect(15, 15, HEALTH * 2, 32);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawRect(15, 15, 200, 32);


     String string = "/";
     Font stringFont = new Font( "HEALTH", Font.PLAIN, 18 );
     g.setFont( stringFont );
     g.drawString(String.valueOf(HEALTH), 15, 15);
     g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);
     if(HEALTH < 100){
        delete g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);// how to make this command work?


         g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 45, 15);
         g.drawString("/", 40, 15);


     }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"i want the command `g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);` to be deleted when my player class goes under 100 hp"_ -- Actually, you don't. Code does not usually modify itself.  You want to write an `if` block that skips that statement if `hp<100`.

Comment: use a `if` statement to handle it , i mean `if(hp>= 100) g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);`

Comment: You should study Java basics first before delving into complex corners, such as GUI coding. You appear to be putting the cart before the horse here.

Comment: Interesting to see how you were able to find out when to DELETE the line of code using the if, but you couldn't think of writing the line of code itself in an if..

Comment: Ad argument of the HP to your function and add the IF(HP==100)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add else to your if block and move the line `g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);` there.

```
 String string = "/";
 Font stringFont = new Font( "HEALTH", Font.PLAIN, 18 );
 g.setFont( stringFont );
 g.drawString(String.valueOf(HEALTH), 15, 15);
 if(HEALTH < 100) {
     // Executes when HEALTH is less than 100
     g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 45, 15);
     g.drawString("/", 40, 15);
 } else {
     // Executes when HEALTH is 100+
     g.drawString(String.valueOf(FULLHEALTH), 50, 15);
 }
```

To better understand go read about flow controll in java. For [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html).

Comment: @DJDOGLAS: you may be acquiring downvotes because it doesn't look like you put a lot of effort into your question. Remember that this isn't Reddit or Facebook - prior research, spell-checking and the occasional use of the Shift key is encouraged and appreciated, as is refraining from txtspk.